# Cannot use Android Studio due to numerous errors

Tags: android, android-studio

I downloaded Android Studio and installed it along with the JDK.

The problem is, whenever I try to create a new  project, it's full of errors. I can't run the Hello World project.

You can see what I downloaded with the SDK manager here:

[image]

Here is the error I get when I create a new project with API 15:

[image]

I found that I need to replace the support library so I replaced the red with green as seen in

[image]

But I still have more then 120 Errors. Some of them refer the the text in the border

[image: see image]

Comment: here is the installed stuff from SDK manager [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/e2ZNh.png)                                                                and here is the what happened after trying to fix the problem [image](http://i.imgur.com/iHFQrL1.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the v23 of the support library, you need to change your compileSdk in the build.gradle to API 23. You can still target API 15, but you just need to compile with the latest SDK and build tools.